# How to make edit book method for Library and book class

Tags: java, oop, methods, modeling

I have to make a library system and it has a Book class and a Library class. Both have an edit book method. The concept is that the librarian searches the book.. it then gets cloned.. the cloned book then gets edited before confirmation.. then placed back in the library replacing the previous book. The Library class edit book method looks like this: `public boolean editBook(String username, Book book)`, and the Book class method looks like this `public boolean editBook(Book book)`.

Now my problem is that the `editBook()` method is supposed to be able to edit every single attribute of the book. How does a method that only takes one attribute (Book) and return a boolean supposed to edit the title, or the author, or the permission type or any of those Its not making sense to me and I've been stuck on this.

Originally i thought that perhaps user input can be taken in the editBook method in order to allow the user to choose what they are actually editing however I just found out we can't do that.

this is what i have for it so far but i was told i can't use it because its calling user input from the book class and it (in this case) can only call user input from the main method. Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks to anyone who can help

```
 Library class method  
 public boolean editBook(String username, Book book) throws CloneNotSupportedException{

    Book clonedBook = book.clone();
    boolean editBook = clonedBook.editBook(clonedBook);
        while(editBook){
            for(Book b: books){
                if(b.getISBNNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(book.getISBNNumber())){
                    int index = books.indexOf(b);
                    books.set(index, clonedBook);
                }
            }
            editBook = false;
        }   
    return true;
}


Book class method

 public boolean editBook(Book book){
    boolean confirm = false;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String y = "";



    do{
    do{
       int x =userInputEnterEditChoice();
       editBookSwitch(x);
       y = userInputMoreAttibutes();

    }while(y.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));

    String z = userInputConfirmEdit();


    if(confirmEdit(z, book)){
                confirm = true;
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("would you like to re edit the book?");
        y = scan.nextLine();
    }
    }while(y.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));



    return confirm;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Now my problem is that the editBook() method is supposed to be able to edit every single attribute of the book. How does a method that only takes one attribute (Book) and return a boolean supposed to edit the title, or the author, or the permission type or any of those Its not making sense to me and I've been stuck on this.

```
public class Book {
int id;
String title;
String Author;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return Author;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    Author = author;
}
}

public class Library {
public boolean editBook(Book book) {
    boolean isEdited = false;
    //This is how you edit the attributes of the book
    book.id=1;
    book.title= "Java Programming";
    book.Author= "John Smith";
    isEdited = true;
    return isEdited;
}
```

}

Comment: But how can I allow the user to input what the new title or author is going to be?

Comment: @Tom, use a Scanner for the user input. Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter a Title: "); etc...

Comment: So i can't take user input from the class directly... i can only take it from the main method (because according to my teacher its bad practice to put scanners in the class methods) so how (when calling the edit book method in the main method) do i take that user input... and give it to the edit book method if it only has one argument?

Comment: You probably want to "pass" the reference to a Book instance between a Library, Patron and Librarian. Cloning is a different sort of thing and probably not what you intend.

Comment: I believe at some point you will need to pass the new title and author name to the editBook method. Are you forbidden to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Long comment, not answer per se.

OOP should generally model real world objects where possible, that's kinda the point.  Why are you cloning books?  Have you considered modeling a real world library?  It would be clearer, at least for me.

Each Library instance has-a Librarian.  Or, even, collection of Librarian objects.

Each Library has-a collection of Book objects.

Can you not say that, also, each Librarian has-a collection of Book objects?

So that, a Librarian can add a Book to their collection of Book instances.  When that happens, the Book gets removed from the Library collection.

Of course, now that the Librarian has-a book, in their collection, they can change the book.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Librarian {

    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

    public Librarian() {
    }

    public void borrowBook(Book book) {
        books.add(book);
    }

    public List<Book> borrowedBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public Book returnBook(Book book) {
        int bookNumber = book.getNumber();
        //your code...
        return books.get(3); //wait, which book?
    }
}
```

Just as a start, food for thought.  Basically, give each book a unique ID when it's created.  You might want to limit a Librarian to only having one book at a time, or maybe two.

Explain it to me like I'm five, please, because I don't understand.  Homework is allowed on SO, if it's HW.  Maybe cloning is a HW requirement?

There are definite problems with the above approach, but, hopefully it might clarify how to approach the model.

Comment: I strongly disagree with "OOP should generally model real world objects" in the sense that you are implying. The object model should reflect the requirements, which in turn reflect the model of a *domain expert*. This might be significantly different than what a layperson might perceive as "real". So it does not matter what *we* see as a Library (i.e. the "real world"), it only matters what the Library is in this particular domain.

Comment: I'll concede that a Librarian "has-a" internal Library of sorts, which defies real-world modeling.  Certainly, you have my attention.  Speak on.  '"This paradigm closely reflects the structure of systems 'in the real world', and it is therefore well suited to model complex systems with complex behaviours"' -Wirth